# Elementos repetidos no se muestra en consulta SQL

Tags: sql

```
 select distinct (select m.nombre from moneda m where m.id=e.moneda_id) as moneda,e.tot_doc_che as chequesDocum, e.tot_imp_che as chequesMontante,
 e.tot_doc_tra as travellDoc,e.tot_imp_tra as travellMontante,sum(e.tot_doc_che)
 from estadisticas e
 group by moneda,chequesDocum,chequesMontante,travellDoc,travellMontante
```

Estoy intentando hacer la suma del campo `tot_doc_che`, y agrupando por `moneda,chequesDocum,chequesMontante,travellDoc,travellMontant`. El tema es que por ejemplo si en algunos de estos 5 campos tengo algún elemento repetido, éste lo omite y no me muestra el registro.
Por ejemplo tengo esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El registro 13 por ejemplo, realmente en la tabla original hay 2 registros que tienen el mismo `chequesmontante`, pero solo sale uno.
¿Habría alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: Precisamente para eso agrupas, para totalizar con alguna función de agregación. Podrías probar con un `GROUP_CONCAT()` o ampliar la pregunta con el dataset y el resultado que esperarías para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @DavidJP Lo que uso es SQL plano. Pues lo que espero es lo que he comentado, deberían aparecer 5 registros de libras, pero solo aparecen 4 porque en chequesmontante del registro 13 coincide en que la tabla original hay 2 números iguales

Comment: Entenderás que tú estás viendo los datos de tu tabla y sabes lo que quieres conseguir, pero nosotros no tenemos esa información. Únicamente nos muestras los resultados de una consulta que no hace lo que esperas. Será un placer ayudarte, pero échanos una mano...

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar el modificador DISTINCT del select?

Comment: @PabloLozano sí, me arroja el mismo resultado

Answer (score 0):

no queda del todo claro tu problema.
Precisamente al meter un campo dentro de un group by lo que haces es agrupar por ese campo de forma que si tienes 2 registros en una tabla con el mismo dato en ese campo agrupado solo vas a tener un resultado en la salida...

Tu query queda más sencilla haciendo esto:

```
 select 
    m.nombre as moneda
   ,e.tot_doc_che as chequesDocum
   ,e.tot_imp_che as chequesMontante
   ,e.tot_doc_tra as travellDoc
   ,e.tot_imp_tra as travellMontante
   ,sum(e.tot_doc_che)
from estadisticas e
inner join moneda m on m.id = e.moneda_id
group by 
    e.moneda_id ,e.tot_doc_che ,e.tot_doc_tra ,e.tot_imp_tra
```

Creo que lo que tienes que hacer es no agrupar por chequesMontante

Comment: Pues lo que espero es lo que he comentado, deberían aparecer 5 registros de libras, pero solo aparecen 4 porque en chequesmontante del registro 13 coincide en que la tabla original hay 2 números iguales